# same merge in for loop instead of repeating the code

Tags: r, loops, merge

How can I do the follow operations:

```
df_2 <- merge(df_2, df_1[,c("id","x_2")], by = "id", all.x = T)
df_3 <- merge(df_3, df_1[,c("id","x_3")], by = "id", all.x = T)
df_4 <- merge(df_4, df_1[,c("id","x_4")], by = "id", all.x = T)
```

in a for loop, instead of repeating the same lines of code?

Comment: Why not just `merge(df_2, df_1[,c("id","x_2", "x_3","x_4")], by = "id", all.x = T)`?

Comment: what do your df_1, df_2, df_3 and df_4 look like? please share a few lines of each of these

Comment: Because I need x_2 only in df_2, x_3 only in df_3, etc. I need the dfs to be separated

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map()`:

```
Map(function(df, x){
  merge(df, df_1[,c("id",x)], by = "id", all.x = T)
},
list(df_2, df_3, df_4),
c("x_2", "x_3", "x_4"))
```

This will give you a list of your desired updated `data.frame()`s but I'd recommend handling multiple similar dfs in a list anyways, this keeps stuff quite a bit tidieR.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get` and `assign` , something like this:

```r
for( i in 2:4 ) {

  x_name <- paste0( "x_",  i+1 )
  d_name <- paste0( "df_", i+1 )
  
  df_i <- get(d_name)
  assign( d_name, merge( df_i, df_1[, c("id",x_name)], by="id", all.x = TRUE )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see Sirius has already covered it but my answer is written so here you go (some small differences) :)

```
df_1 <- data.table(id=1, x_2=2, x_3=3, x_4=4)
df_2 <- data.table(id=1)
df_3 <- data.table(id=1)
df_4 <- data.table(id=1)

indexes <- 2:4

for(i in indexes){
  df_to_update <- sprintf("df_%s", i)
  df_temp <- merge(get(df_to_update), 
                   df_1[,c("id", sprintf("x_%s", i)), with=FALSE],
                   by="id", all.x=TRUE)
  assign(df_to_update, df_temp, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

df_2[]
df_3[]
df_4[]
```